# $^S Doesn't Catch Eval Deaths in Perl

Tags: perl, error-handling

I override dying in Perl for the FastCGI implementation of my code and include a test for `$^S` in the override:

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { 
    return if $^S; 
    say STDERR 'Contents of $^S:' . $^S; 
    &SAFARI::Core::safariErrorLogWriter('Dying from error.'); };
}

sub safariErrorLogWriter {
    my $message = shift;

    return if $^S;

    my ($file,$line,$id) = id(2);

    return if ($file =~ /^\(eval/);

    my $datestring = localtime();
    my $ipAddress = ($ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'} // 'Local') . ': ';    
    $message = $ipAddress . $datestring . ': ' . $message . '; At file: ' . $file . '; line: ' . $line . '; id: ' . $id . "\n"; 

    state $moduleFileHomeDir = require File::HomeDir;
    my $filePath = File::HomeDir->my_home . "/safari_error_log";

    open(my $DATA,">>$filePath") || CORE::die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";
    print $DATA $message;
    close($DATA);
    print STDERR $message;
}
```

The result in each case *shows* $^S as empty, as would be expected since the routine returns upon `$^S` being true.:

```
The result: 
Local: Sat Jul 31 12:00:57 2021: Dying from error.; At file: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/CryptX.pm; line: 14; id:
```

However, during the normal course of loading modules `return if ($file =~ /^\(eval/);` is evaluated as true several times, seemingly indicating `$^S` is not giving the proper result. Several evals slip by both that test *and* `$^S`, for example, the one shown above when loading CryptX.pm, which is performing this eval on line 14:

```
eval { require Cpanel::JSON::XS }
```

Is there anything that would cause `$^S` to be inaccurate? Is there a better way to avoid getting `eval`s in the mix here?

---

I tried to create a minimally reproducible example, but it doesn't seem to exhibit the same behavior, so there must be something else that is messing something up in the much larger code base. I guess that changes my question to: "What could alter the behavior such that `$^S` doesn't work as expected?

This works as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

Core::encodedSessionArray;

package Core;

$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { say STDERR "The result: " . $^S; return if $^S;  &Core::safariErrorLogWriter('Dying from error.'); };


sub safariErrorLogWriter {
    my $message = shift;

    return if $^S;

    my ($file,$line,$id) = id(2);

    state $evalRegEx = qr#^\(eval#;
    return if ($file =~ /$evalRegEx/);

    my $datestring = localtime();
    my $ipAddress = ($ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'} // 'Local') . ': ';    
    $message = $ipAddress . $datestring . ': ' . $message . '; At file: ' . $file . '; line: ' . $line . '; id: ' . $id . "\n"; 

    state $moduleFileHomeDir = require File::HomeDir;
    my $filePath = File::HomeDir->my_home . "/safari_error_log";

    open(my $DATA,">>$filePath") || CORE::die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";
    print $DATA $message;
    close($DATA);
    print STDERR $message;
}

sub _makeIpKeyCryptObject {
    my $ipAddress = $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'};
    $ipAddress =~ s/\.//g;

    # Make a 16 byte key out of the IP address info.
    my $key = substr(sprintf("%016d", $ipAddress), 0, 16);

    state $moduleCryptModeCBCEasy = require Crypt::Mode::CBC::Easy;
    return Crypt::Mode::CBC::Easy->new(key => $key);        
}

sub encodedSessionArray {
    my $self = shift;
    my $params = shift;

    $params->{'sessionId'} = 0 unless $params->{'sessionId'};
    $params->{'uid'} = '0' unless $params->{'uid'};

    my $crypt = $self->_makeIpKeyCryptObject;
    my $encrypted = $crypt->encrypt(($params->{'sessionId'}, $params->{'uid'},time()));

    $encrypted =~ s/\n/\\n/g;

    return $encrypted;

}

1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, the [$^S variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5ES) shows

> Current state of the interpreter.
>
> ```
> $^S         State  
> ---------   -------------------------------------  
> undef       Parsing module, eval, or main program  
> true (1)    Executing an eval  
> false (0)   Otherwise
> ```

---

The error message shown in the question, apparently triggered when `CryptX.pm` died inside of an `eval` statement, is printed from a sub called from the `__DIE__` handler.  In my tests `$^S` is `1` in a situation like that, but my tests aren't what is happening there.

When in your code does this happen -- when loading `CryptX`?  What other code gets involved? Does your handler get *that* `die` or something re-thrown along the way (not from an `eval`)? The `CryptX` loads C code first. Basics:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    say "in __DIE__ handler, \$^S = $^S. call a sub";
    handler(@_)
};

sub handler {
    print "in handler(), got: @_";
    say "\$^S = $^S"
}

eval { require NoMod };  # note: in this namespace, not in another package

say "done";
```

This prints (my `@INC` suppressed)

```
in __DIE__ handler, $^S = 1. call a sub
in handler(), got: Can't locate NoMod.pm in @INC (@INC contains:...) at... line 15.
$^S = 1
done
```

But if a `die` is thrown from an `eval` *in another package* then my handler isn't triggered.<sup>†</sup>  That appears to be the case in your code -- but then how does that error handling get triggered?  This is an additional big complication with what is shown.

Altogether I wouldn't conclude that `$^S` is wrong but rather that we don't know what is going on, much as stated in the second part of the question.

The question also says

> ...during the normal course of loading modules `return if ($file =~ /^\(eval/);` is evaluated as true several times,...

(the quoted `return...` statement is in a sub shown to be called out of a `__DIE__` handler)

It is mentioned in comments that the sub `id`, which return is assigned to `$file`, comes from `CGI::Carp` and is much like `caller`. Then `$file` is a (misnamed) name of a sub that's been called? Then in case of a match that would presumably be an `eval` -- but we don't know how closely that `id` mimics `caller`. Then, `id(2)` is presumably the frame level in the callstack? Are we still in `eval` execution? This all matters but is unclear. (And *why* `2`?)

But above all note what the docs say by the end of [%SIG in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#%25SIG)

> Having to even think about the `$^S` variable in your exception handlers is simply wrong. `$SIG{__DIE__}` as currently implemented invites grievous and difficult to track down errors. Avoid it and use an `END{}` or `CORE::GLOBAL::die` override instead.

I'd recommend to heed that advice.  Here is an [article from Effective Perler on it](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/05/override-die-with-end-or-coreglobaldie/)

A few more notes

- Pass `@_` from `__DIE__` handler to the next sub so to see the error
- That `&` in front of `SAFARI::Core::safariErrorLogWriter` seems unneeded for that sub. It doesn't affect this discussion but I don't see that you need it there
- The `( caller(LEVEL) )[7]` says whether this comes from `require`. Could be useful here

---

<sup>†</sup> Unless it's defined in a `BEGIN` block, along with subs it uses.  But then this is a bad idea since then *all* code after that point gets affected, libraries included

Comment: I'll check out that article. As to `$file`, it is produced from calling `id(2)`. I cannot seem to find `id` in perldoc, but I had included after finding it on StackOverflow as a way to determine where the exception occurred. I also override CORE::GLOBAL::die but for some reason ran into an issue that led me to playing with `$SIG{__DIE__}` too. I'll revisit that decision... Thanks!

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler Thanks for the comment -- I saw how `$file` is obtained but there is no `id` in Perl. I'd expect that to be a part of a stacktrace of some sort (since it tests for `(eval` pattern) but that's not clear, while it matters. Sorry I can't help more but it's unclear what exactly is going on.  With convoluted error checking the name of the game is "simplify," that's one thing i can say.

Comment: I need my memory to last longer than it does. I had taken that function out of `CGI::Carp`. It's really just providing a slight adjustment to `caller(2)`. `$file` is being reported directly from what `caller` reports. In any case "simplify" sounds great and I'm going to see if I can do that.

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler Thank you.  I looked and  thought  more carefully, and updated the post.  I still don't know what is going on altogether as information isn't there but hopefully extra discussion helps